# Finding a permutation matrix for almost identical permuted matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Given $A= \begin{pmatrix}
4  & 2 & 3 & 5\\ 
3 & 3 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix} $ 
and $B= \begin{pmatrix}
3 + \epsilon_1 & 3 & 1 & 0\\ 
4  & 2+ \epsilon_2 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} $ 

 How can I compute the permutation matrix? 
I.e. find a `Doubly stochastic matrix` that satisfies
$A^T *P\approx B^T$
e.g. here P is  $P= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $
edit: I'm looking for a closed form solution, and not iteratively finding the "most similar row" in each corresponding matrix

Comment: Why do you not want to iteratively find the identical rows? It seems to me like the fastest way to get a solution.

Comment: And if we don't enforce it to be only ones, but Doubly stochastic? I'm trying to find a correspondence between two almost identical (permuted) matrices, and hoped that starting from identical (permuted) matrices would be a good start

Comment: That would be a good thing to write in the question post itself, so we know what problem we are _actually_ solving, so that we don't give you solutions that aren't generalizable. What you have here is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and those are generally undesirable.

Comment: You are right, thank you